# Why I get no output when use (sh "top") in clojure?

Tags: clojure, sh

I try to get output from [sh](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.shell/sh) command but don't see any.

```
(:use [clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])


(sh "ls" "-aul"); <-- WORKS
=>
{:exit 0,
 :out "total 136       
   -rw-r--r--    1 snaggs  staff    113 Jan  8 14:17 .babelrc
   drwxr-xr-x   15 snaggs  staff    510 Jan 12 14:14 .hg
```

The command `(sh "top")` - no output. I know that `top` command is like listener. So how can I configure `sh` to get output from `top`. Suppose `tail -f` should be the same behavior.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you expect `(sh "top")` should return?

Comment: @OlegTheCat  string as `Processes: 325 total, 2 running, 323 sleeping, 2224 threads ..... `

Comment: Will `top -l 1` do the job?

Answer (score 3):

First make sure, that you run your version of `top` in "batch mode", which just prints to stdout ad infinitum.  For Linux and FreeBSD this is `top -b`.  Next `sh` can not be used for this problem, as it waits for the command to finish.  So the same can be done via the `ProcessBuilder` from Java.  E.g.

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

; start `top -b`
(let [process (-> (ProcessBuilder. ["top" "-b"]) .start)]
  ; get the stdout of the process
  (with-open [stdout (io/reader (.getInputStream process))]
    (loop []
      ; read a line, handle it, until EOF
      (when-let [line (.readLine stdout)]
        (println line) ; work here
        (recur)))))
```

(note this lacks a final `(.destroy process)` call)

#### Original answer why `(sh "top")` does not return

Not strictly a Clojure problem.  You have to start `top` with the following params for the linux `top`: `-n1` (only one iteration, then stop) and `-b` (batchmode, just write to stdout).  Other versions might differ here.

```
user=> (use '[clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])
nil
user=> (sh "top" "-n1" "-b")
{:err "",
 :exit 0,
 :out "top - 14:06:47 up 126 days,  5:21,  5 users,  load average: 0.93, 0.67, 1.12 ,,,
```

In your example, you just ran `top` as with you would do from the command line.  So it starts and runs waiting for you to quit or kill it - blocking your REPL.

Comment: On macOS, `top`'s logging mode should be used instead: `(sh "top" "-l" "1")`

Comment: On FreeBSD `top` alone is enough, since it detects there is no terminal.  But use `top -b` to be on the safe side.

Comment: @cfrick I know how to run one instance, but I need continues task, like `tail -f`. Maybe I need to use streams